# My Connection already open but why the system said it closed?

Tags: asp.net, connection, sql-server-ce, executenonquery

`ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.`

Why always the system returns that message?

I have a sub:

```
Private Sub Initialization()    

    If myCEConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then '--> *1
        Try
            myCEConnection.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If

    Dim reader As SqlCeDataReader
    Dim myCommand As SqlCeCommand = myCEConnection.CreateCommand()

    myCommand.CommandText = "Command goes here"
    Try
        reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader() 
    Catch ex As Exception '--> *2

    End Try

    myCEConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

And I called that function from this sub:

```
Public myCEConnection As New SqlCeConnection("Connection String Goes Here")

Private Sub Report()
    If myCEConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then '--> *1
        Try
            myCEConnection.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If

    Initialization()

    myCEConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

When I try to set a breakpoint to the `*1` line, the system returns `myCEConnection.State = Open {1}`. But when I continue to run the breakpoint, on line `*2` I got: `ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is Closed.`

[image]

What's wrong with the code?

Note: Every sub/function on the class always have the `If myCeConnection.State = .....` part to check the connection is already open or not. Maybe this caused the problem but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Are you sure the connection is open? Can you recheck and verify if the connectionstate is open after the try catch clause.

Comment: You're checking the state at *1 however you haven't opened it yet. How could it possibly be open before the `myCEConnection.Open()` line? And since your `Catch` doesn't do anything, how are you sure that the connection has been opened, unless you actually spit out an exception instead of simply ignoring it?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code above, pls take a look. And yes, the connection is already open. I call it from another sub that has already open the connection.

Comment: where have you defined myCommand? (in the debugging step image you have attached)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to associate the connection and the command:

```
myCommand.Connection = myCEConnection
```

Also consider changing your code into something like this:

```
Dim reader As SqlCeDataReader

Using myCEConnection As New SqlCeConnection("Connection String Goes Here")
  myCEConnection.Open()
  Using myCommand As SqlCeCommand = myCEConnection.CreateCommand()
    myCommand.Connection = myCEConnection
    myCommand.CommandText = "Command goes here"
    reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
  End Using
End Using
```

You don't really need the Try-Catch'es, and my guess is the initial `myCEConnection.Open()` is throwing an exception, but you never see it because of the Try-Catch.

Comment: I would say yes: The Using statement is powerful and convenient, and keeping open connections around is generally a bad idea. Did you remember to associate the connection with command? I've updated my sample...